# what ftp server to use for 1 user on Centos

Tags: ftp, backup

We have a CentOS 5 machine running that gathers backups from a few different places.
We rotate backups in a folder for every day of the week.

Now we want to pull those backups offline by opening up an FTP instance on the centos machine so that we can just schedule a backup job to take all files from the backup folder.

We are open to other solutions for getting the backups offline.

To be precise: all our backups are in /backups
If FTP would be the best solution to get the files, what server do we use? VSFTPD?

We want to be able to create 1 user (only ftp) that has READ permissions to 1 directory only (/backups)

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Proftpd, anyway why not SFTP, FTPS... orrr SCP? FTP is bit old ;)

Comment: well, we are working on Windows workstations and want an easy way to grab those files from a directory. Can we do that with SFTP/SCP?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use VSFTPD, but as you can probably imagine, there are dozens of distributions that can do exactly the same.

Comment: Is there any reason you'd pick VSFTPD over any other?